# How to get DOM HTML in Go

Tags: go, goquery

I'm writing a parser HTML in Go. I need to get HTML and pass it to another function.

I did it so:

1. Can`t pass "doc" to another function

```golang
receivedURL, err := http.Get("http://lavillitacafe.com/")
doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(receivedURL.Body)
//"linkScrape" this is another function
contactURL := linkScrape(doc)
```

and

2. HTML is transferred in parts to another function.

```golang
resp, err := http.Get("http://lavillitacafe.com/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    for true {

        bs := make([]byte, 1014)
        n, err := resp.Body.Read(bs)
                contactURL := linkScrape(bs[:n])
        if n == 0 || err != nil{
            break
        }
    }
```

How do I do it right?

Comment: Why do you say you can't pass `doc` to `linkScrape`?

Comment: @EliBendersky  cannot use 'doc' as type goquery.Document

Comment: Could it be because `doc` is a `*Document`? (pointer type) What's the signature/declaration of `linkScrape`?

Comment: @EliBendersky linkScrape(domHtml goquery.Document)  string{}

Comment: I added an answer - please take a look

Comment: @EliBendersky Thank you. 
I need to learn to read English.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic `goquery` example adjusted to your use case:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func findHeader(d *goquery.Document) string {
    header := d.Find("h1").Text()
    return header
}

func main() {
    // create from a string
    data := `
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </body>
</html>`

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(findHeader(doc))
}
```